# How to execute a function asynchronously in c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads, threadpool

I'm now working for a c++ queue managing program. I added my dummy code and sequence diagram. There are many Data data from SomeClass::Handler. So I have to save all data to my queue. And worker has to manipulate data for converting into a Command instance. So I want to make a thread for generating command from data. But I want to limit the number of worker thread to one so that the number of command generating process is always one. After generating command, I want to return this command to SomeClass.

I'm totally confused how to implement this design. Any helps will be appreciated.

Edited for more specification.

1. How to restrict the number of worker thread, not avoiding pushing data to queue?
2. How to return a command instance from a woker thread?

`

```
void MyClass::notify_new_data()
{
  // if there are no worker, I want to start new worker
  // But how?
}

// I want to limit the number of worker to one.
void MyClass::worker() {
  // busy loop, so should I add sleep_for(time) at the bottom of this func?
  while(queue.empty() == false) {
    MyData data;
    {
      lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
      data = queue.pop();
    }
    // do heavy processing with data
    auto command = do_something_in_this thread();
    // how to pass this command to SomeClass!?
  }
}

// this class is called via aother thread.
void MyClass::push_data(MyData some_data) {
  {
    lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    queue.push(some_data);
  }
  notify_new_data();
}

void SomeClass::Handler(Data d) {
  my_class.push(data);
}

void SomeClass::OnReceivedCommand(Command cmd) {
  // receive command
}
```

[image]

Comment: TMI. You need to make your question more specific. "But worker should be one" -- my King's English isn't exactly top notch, but I'm fairly certain that this combination of words doesn't quite connect, with each other.

Comment: sorry. modified my question

Answer (score 2):

The question is not very clear. I am assuming that:

- You need a **single** worker thread that executes some operations asynchronously.
- You need to retrieve the result of the computation of the worker thread from another thread.

---

> How to restrict the number of worker thread, not avoiding pushing data to queue?

Look into [*"thread pooling"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool). Create a thread pool with a single worker thread that reads from a thread-safe queue. This is pretty much what your `MyClass::worker()` is doing.

> // busy loop, so should I add sleep_for(time) at the bottom of this func?

You can either use **condition variables** and locking mechanisms to prevent busy waiting, or use a mature lock-free queue implementation like [moodycamel::ConcurrentQueue](https://github.com/cameron314/concurrentqueue).

> // how to pass this command to SomeClass!?

The cleanest and safest way of passing data between threads is using [**futures** and **promises**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises). The [`std::future` page on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) is a good place to start.

> // if there are no worker, I want to start new worker

I would create a thread pool containing a single active worker before starting your computations, so that you never have to check if a worker is available. If you cannot do that, an [`std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) flag signaling whether or not a worker was created should suffice.